# Spark/Databricks: How to know the latest identity value after insert into?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm writing on a Databricks table using PySpark `insert into` command. As far as I checked, there is no `scope_identity` and `IDENT_CURRENT`. How can I check the latest id increment after an insert into command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [monotonically_increasing_id()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/sql/gen-unique-increasing-values#use-monotonically_increasing_id-for-unique-but-not-consecutive-numbers) which generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers.

After `insertInto` command, store that table in a dataframe like below:

```
df = spark.table("employees")
```

Then follow this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
col, max as max_, struct, monotonically_increasing_id
)
res = (df
    .withColumn("_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    .select(max(struct("_id", *df.columns))
    .alias("tmp")).select(col("tmp.*"))
    .drop("_id"))
```

Now you can see the **latest inserted row** after this.

**Output:**
[image]

Also, as an alternative method, you can combine this `monotonically_increasing_id()` with `row_number()` and can achieve your requirement. Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/sql/gen-unique-increasing-values#combine-monotonically_increasing_id-with-row_number-for-two-columns) to learn more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this indeed works in some cases. In my case, I am using the identity column. As in here: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html

Is there a way to get the latest id after inserting into the table?

Comment: In your case as you are using an identity column which is increasing on every insertion, you can get the latest id after insertion by that column by using this code ```select * from employees where identity_column in (select max(employees.identity_column) from employees);```. if you are using decreasing identity column just use ```min```.

Comment: In a race condition where another user might have updated the table at the same time, I might be querying their id, not the one that I inserted in. Then I guess this is a shortcoming from Spark/Databricks

Comment: spark SQL we can do like triggers in sql but it needs some manual update using [merge](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge). First we have to add the LastModifieddate column with the default current datetime. The other user should update the table like [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/08/27/enabling-spark-sql-ddl-and-dml-in-delta-lake-on-apache-spark-3-0.html)
and update the LastModifieddate column to current datetime when the identity id matches. Then you can get the latest updated record anytime by the recent LastModifieddate column.